# how to merge same value rows in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that looks somewhat like this:

Table:Orders

```
OrderID  ProductID   Quantity   StoreID   OrderDate
01       1           5          1         05-10-2014
02       2           2          4         05-10-2014
03       1           1          3         05-10-2014
04       3           1          3         05-10-2014
```

Now i want to retrieve from above table "orders" data looks like this :

Retrieve Result

```
ProductID       Quantity   StoreID    OrderDate 
(Product Merge) (SUM)      (COUNT)    (Date*)
1               6          2          05-10-2014
2               2          1          05-10-2014
3               1          1          05-10-2014
```

As per above "retrieve result" i want to merge my table "orders" data with ProductID

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you need `GROUP BY`. You group them by the productID and select the sum of the quantities

```
SELECT SUM(Quantity), COUNT(StoreID), ... FROM Orders GROUP BY ProductID
```